# smallest length of reads in 3'quantseq?

Tags: rna-seq, rna

I am studying about RNA seq, and especially about 3'Quantseq(tagseq, 3primeseq). I wonder if there is a cutoff for the reads length. By this I mean that given that 3'quantseq targets the end of the genes and 3'UTR, then for example if reads are 75bp, then could be the case that only 3'UTR is mapped and not coding region? I am interested in Human Sapiens. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi @user could you supply more detail please? A 3' UTR in viruses is a very specific region of the genome and has a precise biological meaning and purpose of study. I doubt this is your investigation, but please edit your post to be clearer.

Comment: Is it better now?Thank you!

Comment: Lets see. If you have no take up then it would be an idea to revise the question to fully explain your study. Generally it is seen as bad form to provide minimal detail, but sometimes a breif specific question connects with a brief specific answer.  This is not my area so it is difficult for me to judge.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: Yes, that can very well happen depending on the average fragment size, the read length and the length of the UTR.